# Accidentally uninstall react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

I accidentally uninstall react native  on my project

```
npm uninstall --save react-native map
```

What i'm gonna  do is uninstalling react-native-map, but i miss one '-' character. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can reinstall it by `npm install --save react-native@yourversionnumber`

Comment: How to uninstall the react native? Now it is in C:// I want to install it in D://. What should I do?

Comment: You mean a project with react native?

Comment: Just not start to install react native(installed in C://). created the project in D:// and when I try to start project it shows as "A complete log of this run can be found in C://

Comment: C:\Users\Sk\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-native-app -> C:\Use
oaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-native-app\build\index.js

Comment: sorry i cannot understand what you mean but i suggest start a new question and you will find someone to help